# Sorting columns left to right in Google Sheets by alphabet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

i have a spreadsheet in google sheets and i need sort columns left to right

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It can be done manually (select, [transponse](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yO3fY_Lkzhw), sort, transpose back), but if you want a script by some reason, here you go:

```
function myFunction() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  
  // credits: stackoverflow.com/a/36164530/14265469
  const transpose = m => m[0].map((x,i) => m.map(x => x[i]))

  var [col1, col2, ...etc] = transpose(data);
  var table = transpose([col1, col2, ...etc.sort()]);

  sheet.clearContents().getRange(1,1,table.length,table[0].length).setValues(table)
}
```

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

Comment: it works, but i need first and second col freeze

Comment: It doesn't change the first and second columns. If they were frozen they will stay frozen. I just tested it: https://imgur.com/zNcMlbT.png --> https://imgur.com/nkysEMs.png

Comment: Have you tried the script one more time? Can you provide feedback. I could help if you have a problem with the code.